# AngularJS directive - setting order for multiple directive elements (not priority for directives, but priority for the elements)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, element, order-of-execution

Considering this markup with a directive "foo":

```
<div foo run="3"></div>
<div foo run="1"></div>
<div foo run="2"></div>
```

What is a good approach for causing "foo" to run in the specified order rather than from top to bottom (3,1,2)?
The only thing I can think to do would be tracking what has run and returning false on the items that are not in order, then making angular try to run them all again and repeat until they are all done. That sounds terrible to me though, because it would have to repeat so many times... Does Angular have something built-in that can be used? Is there an ideal approach for dealing with this?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have a little more information about what you are doing within the foo directive, and how the order is important.  With a parent directive, you may be able to capture the child directives, then process them in a separate step.

Comment: Hmm. That's an interesting thought. I'll crunch on it for a bit. What my actual directive is doing is loading various kinds of content, some of which is drastically more important than others. It's actually a plugin loader and deals with lazy loading of controllers/templates. It has all loaded very quickly so far, but I want to try it with a good priority system in place also. At the moment, the content just loads from top to bottom. This could be an issue where there is a left side-bar that would take priority over the main content body.

Comment: I see, you mean remotely requested content, and you want to manage the load order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's my solution, although it's more a template.

**[Fiddle (check the console log to see the result)](http://jsfiddle.net/OverZealous/8aQSL/4/)**

I've wrapped the `foo` directive in a `fooParent` directive, like so:

```html
<div foo-parent>
    <div foo run="3"></div>
    <div foo run="1"></div>
    <div foo run="2"></div>
</div>
```

The `fooParent` directive exists pretty much to do three things:

1. Expose a function to `foo` items so they can be added to a general list
2. Maintain a list of `foos`, which will be sorted during post-linking
3. Process each `foo` in the run order specified.

It looks like this:

```
app.directive('fooParent', function() {
    var foos = [];
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            this.addFoo = function(runOrder, element) {
                foos.push({
                    run: 1*runOrder, // make sure run is an integer
                    element: element
                });
            };
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            foos.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.run - b.run;
            });
            // process all children here
            angular.forEach(foos, function(foo) {
                console.log(foo);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And `foo` simply looks like:

```
app.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^fooParent',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fooParent) {
            fooParent.addFoo(attrs.run, element);
        }
    };
});
```

Obviously, you will have to figure out the best way to handle remotely loading your content, especially if you want it to be serially loaded.  Your `foo` directive would become much more simplified, since the loading and processing would have to occur within `fooParent`.

Comment: looks great. I'm going to dive into in the morning and see where I get :)

Comment: Just a heads up, the elements are nested in one another, which is not desirable. I'm also getting 2,1,3 rather than 3,1,2.

Comment: Oh, of course. We left off the </div>. Haha, fatigue works wonders on the mind :)

Comment: I corrected the nesting issue (yup, it was too late to be writing), and I also corrected the conversion of run to an integer, which will help with sorting.  Finally, if you want to run the highest run-number first, change the sorting function to `b.run - a.run` (swapping `a` and `b`).

Comment: I just did the same thing :) It does appear to be working great! I have an idea I'd also like to try, just for the sake of it. I'll post in a bit.

Comment: What I don't understand at all is how all the "foo" directives link functions run THEN "fooParent" link function. I don't see anything telling it not to do the default top to bottom, which would be parent then child.

Comment: I had to read up on that myself.  The reason is the standalone `link` function is a **post** link function.  It is called [after all the children have been linked](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#postlinkingfunction).

Comment: Ugh — if you click that link, the important bit gets hidden below the fixed menu bar.  You'll have to scroll up a bit.

Comment: I see. I always though it was pre by default. Dunno how I missed that. So here's my variation. What do you think? http://jsbin.com/apumaj/2/

Comment: Use this link to see the code from my link above. I didn't think that it might not be clear what to do to people that don't know jsbin. http://jsbin.com/apumaj/2/edit

Comment: That's cleaner, in some ways, but it's wasteful in that you are having to query the DOM to get a list of all the items.  It feels more fragile to me.

Comment: I've learned the error of my ways! The parent element isn't non-semantic as I was thinking. It's irrelevant. It occurred to me that the parent directive could just be applied to the html tag and all is well. This way adds a bit of flexibility and encapsulation and that's good stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Credit to OverZealous for inspiring my answer. Test it here. http://jsbin.com/apumaj/21/edit

the html (directive output will be displayed in this order, of course)

```
<div foo run="7"></div>
<div foo run="3"></div>
<div foo run="1"></div>
<div foo run="2"></div>
```

and the directive (to make the directive output load in "run" order) should be self-explanatory

```
app.directive('foo', function() {
  var foos = [];
  var foosLength = document.querySelectorAll('[foo]').length;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          foos.push({element:element, run:attrs.run});
          if (foos.length === foosLength) {
             foos.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.run - b.run;
            });
            console.log('ran in this order:');
            for (var i=0; i<foosLength; ++i) {
              //process foos!
              var foo = foos[i];
              console.log(foo.run);
              foo.element.text(foo.run);
            }
          }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I chose this method over the solution proposed by OverZealous because it does not require a non-semantic and otherwise unnecessary dom element and an extra directive. It is more understandable/readable and the performance should be marginally better.

Comment: and I've since changed my mind and started to like OverZealous's answer :)

Comment: Chosing not to have a parent element forces you to use DOM methods (querySelector). Side note is that both solutions do not work when you have nested `<foo>`s, unless you want to select them all regardless of the nesting depth. The Angular philosophy is to use child/parent directives in combination with `require` to define dependencies between DOM elements. Therefore I think @OverZealous' solution is more elegant.

Comment: @frankvanwijk absolutely. That's why I marked it accepted. :) My answer does solve my actual problem slightly neater because I needed it to be global, but it's certainly better to use the parent element to make it global, rather than force it. I didn't realize this back then.